# Not able to send values to textbox after popup closed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, element

I have a `TextBox` where in I need to send some numbers after selecting some value in the `popup`. Here, the `popup` will close after I select some value and click on `OK` button.

I am getting `Element not clickable point` error when I run the script.

I have tried following workarounds but nothing worked for me.
1) putting explicit wait for some seconds.
2) tried using java script executor

Please help.

Comment: Please share your HTML where you want to automate.. and your logic as well...

Answer (score 0):

Just an example .You may want to try Selenium.Interactions

```
 public class TestPopUpElement{
public static Actions action;

public void TestPopUp(){
action = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement ElementToStore= driver.FindElement(By.XPath    
("XPath of the Element"));    
action.MoveToElement(Lightbox).Click().Perform();
}
}
```